# How to avoid using a lots of ternary operators for translation of value to text

Tags: jasper-reports, conditional-operator

I am using *JasperReports* to create some reports of a *Django* web application.

Let's say that I have a model that has an id and a value. This value is a *Django* choice so I end up in my database with only the keys and not the values (the values are in my code). To make it more clear for people that don't use *Django*, I end up with something like that in my database:

```
id value
1  'GD'
2  'VG'
3  'VG'
4  'VG'
5  'GD'
6  'AV'
7  'GD'
8  'AV'
```

I want to display *Good* instead of *'GD'*, *Average* instead of *'AV'* and *Very Good* instead of *VG* in my report. I know that this can be done with two equally not desirable to me options:

1. Create a new table in my database that has key - value and join that in the *JR* query. 
   I really hate this because I'd need to create around 10 such tables.
2. Use the ternary operator to display the correct value:

```java
field.equals("GD")?"Good":(field.equals("AV")?"Average":(field.equals("VG")?"Very good":"-"))
```

I also hate this because it would be very complicated if I had, for instance, 10 key-value pairs.

My ideal solution would be to define a dictionary (*HashMap*) variable in my report that would contain all the key value pairs and then just do a *`DICTIONARY.get(field)`* to represent the field value. Can this be done ? Can you possibly propose another, better solution?

Please don't tell me to alter my database design, I know that some people won't like but it perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this issue with help of *Java*. For example, the [*Guava library*](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) can help us in solving this task.

#### Using report's parameter

We can add the parameter of *`java.util.Map`* type and use it for extracting the value by the key (it can be the *value* field from your sample)

The sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="using_map" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e566b23d-ca97-472e-9cc3-8073573f4537">
    <import value="com.google.common.collect.*"/>
    <import value="com.google.common.base.*"/>
    <parameter name="values" class="java.util.Map" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String>().put("GD", "Good").put("AV", "Average").build()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="value" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f23f6abc-cd9b-4415-a591-cb7a51ad0392" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f23f6abc-cd9b-4415-a591-cb7a51ad0392" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Value]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f23f6abc-cd9b-4415-a591-cb7a51ad0392" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Value from Map]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8eb8bbef-430b-4ad1-b592-000fe7ccce9f" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8eb8bbef-430b-4ad1-b592-000fe7ccce9f" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8eb8bbef-430b-4ad1-b592-000fe7ccce9f" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{values}.get($F{value})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

In this sample we use [*ImmutableMap.Builder*](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html) class for creating and filling the *Map*.

The result will be (via *iReport* preview):

[image: The result in iReport]

As you can see that the third columns contains *null* value for values that are not in *Map*.

---

*Note*: Don't forget to add *Guava* library to classpath.

#### Using scriptlet

You can do the same with help of [***Scriptlets***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/scriptlet/index.html#scriptlet).

You can write the simple *Java* class with static method, for example for getting value from the *Map*.

#### Using internationalization mechanism

May be the simplest way is to use report's [***internationalization support***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/i18n/index.html#i18n).

You can attach the *properties* file with values to your report.

The sample of *jrxml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="localization" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" resourceBundle="marks" uuid="a5d74b61-8d62-41ac-b874-76d6f40da79e">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="value" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f23f6abc-cd9b-4415-a591-cb7a51ad0392" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f23f6abc-cd9b-4415-a591-cb7a51ad0392" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Value]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f23f6abc-cd9b-4415-a591-cb7a51ad0392" x="200" y="0" width="114" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Value from Properties]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8eb8bbef-430b-4ad1-b592-000fe7ccce9f" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8eb8bbef-430b-4ad1-b592-000fe7ccce9f" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8eb8bbef-430b-4ad1-b592-000fe7ccce9f" x="200" y="0" width="114" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[str($F{value})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The *marks.properties* file:

```properties
GD=Good
AV=Average
VG=Very Good
```

And the result will be (with *iReport* preview):

[image: The result in iReport]

I've used the *`str()`* method and the *`$R{}`* syntax.

Comment: @Serafeim I've just add another simple solution

Comment: thanks a lot this seems even simpler. Just a quick question, where should I put the marks.properties file ?  I am using jasperserver to create my reports. Thanks again !

Comment: You should deploy *properties* file as resource. For more information you can read the topic *Localizing Reports* of *JasperReports Server User Guide*. The sample of report with *properties* file is also available on *JR Server*. You are welcome :)